# Filtering and passing csv data in d3

Tags: csv, d3.js, pie-chart

I would like to be able to filter csv data for use in a series of dynamic pie charts. (That is, the user will be presented with an initial pie chart, and will be able to click on a specific pie wedge/category to pull up another pie chart showing details for that category).

This is the relevant code, to be called within an "update" function with the "selected" variable as input:

```
d3.csv("budget.csv", function(i,data) {
var csv = data.filter(function(row) {
    return row["category"] == selected});  
var g = revenue.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(csv))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    //This doesn't work
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.csv.name); });
```

Color, arc, and pie were previously (successfully) defined with scale.ordinal, svg.arc, and layout.pie.

The above code nearly works -- but doesn't get the fill color of the pie pieces right. When I use **d.data.name** in the last line (see below), the code works fine. Can someone please explain to me why?

```
    //This works
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });
```

It probably goes without saying, but the usual caveats [new to d3] and apologies [sorry if this is obvious] apply.
Thanks!
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout) the pie layout returns:

- value - the data value, returned by the value accessor.
- startAngle - the start angle of the arc in radians.
- endAngle - the end angle of the arc in radians.
- data - the original datum for this arc.

So in your code "csv" holds all your row objects. Calling the pie layout takes these objects and a (possibly implied) value accessor to compute start and end angles for all your wedges. It returns news objects, in the same order, with the four properties listed above. The "data" property stores the original object (from your csv list) that generated the wedge.

So following all that it makes perfect sense:

```
csv: [{name:bob, value:10}, {name:alice, value:10}]
```

becomes

```
pie(csv): [{value: 10, startAngle:0, endAngle:3.14, data: {name:bob, value:10}},
           {value: 10, startAngle:3.14, endAngle:6.28, data: {name:alice, value:10}}]
```

you should theoretically also be able to use

```
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(csv[i].name); });
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much. The "csv[i].name" works! And your explanation helped this all make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `d.csv`. When loading the csv data, d3 creates the `data` properties at which you can access all csv data. Just use `d.data`.

The `data` properties are actually filled when you call `.data(pie(csv))`. This will tell d3 to *join* the `csv` data with the selected html/svg elements (i.e., the **g.arc**'s).

After that there is usually no need to access the *raw* `csv` array anymore when styling your **path** elements via `.style("fill", ...)`.

Comment: Thanks Juve. This definitely helps clarify things.